# PosgreSQL: Convert JSON array to JSON object

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.5

I need some help in converting JSON array in postgresTO JSON object as below. Please Note the keys are not known in advance, any key can show up in the JSON array. Is there a way to just flatten it out.

INPUT:-

```
 [{"col1": "1", "col2": null, "col3": "7"}, {"col4": "19"}, {"col5": "19", "col6":"18"}]
```

OUTPUT:-

```
{"col1": "1", "col2": null, "col3": "7", "col4": "19", "col5": "19", "col6":"18"}
```

Thank you

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 and 9.5 are [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible. Additionally: the JSON support in modern Postgres versions is way better than it was back then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First flatten (using `json_array_elements` and then `json_each` on each array element) and then aggregate back with `json_object_agg`.

```sql
select json_object_agg(k, v) 
from json_array_elements
('[
  {"col1":"1","col2":null,"col3":"7"},
  {"col4":"19"},
  {"col5":"19","col6":"18"}
]') as ja 
cross join lateral json_each(ja) as jl(k, v);
```